# Can I include a Sender ID when sending AT commands to a mobile phone?

Tags: mobile, at-command, sender-id

I wish to include a Sender ID instead of a phone number when sending messages using a phone using AT commands. It seems this is not possible. Can anyone confirm this is indeed impossible using AT commands?

Answer (score 2):

In default Text Message mode yes. But when you set your modem to work in PDU mode then you can send raw SMS PDU's where you can set the originator address to any telephone number or alphanumeric text.

Comment: So does this mean that any sender can be spoofed?

Comment: Yes, it will appear to be spoofed then.

Comment: I don't think it's possible even in PDU mode. http://www.gsm-modem.de/sms-pdu-mode.html